# Нужно разделить данные на три категории

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Нужно разделить все фильмы на три категории:

1. `< 90`, если фильм длится менее 90 минут;
2. `90-120`, если фильм длится от 90 минут до 2 часов (включительно);
3. `> 120`, если фильм длится больше 2 часов

```
if data['duration']<90:
    data['movie_duration_category'] = 1
elif 90<= data['duration'] <= 120:
    data['movie_duration_category'] = 2
else:
    data['movie_duration_category'] = 3
```

Почему-то не работает.

Comment: Отформатируйте вопрос нормально.

Comment: `data` - это Pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: @MaxU да , именно так

Answer (score 5, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df["movie_duration_category"] = pd.cut(df["duration"], [0, 89, 120, np.inf], labels=[1,2,3])
```

---

результат:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
   duration movie_duration_category
0        70                       1
1        90                       2
2       100                       2
3       120                       2
4       200                       3
```

Answer (score 1):

На Kaggle я видел, что часто делают так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': np.random.randint(1, 240, 100)})
df['movie_duration_category'] = 3
df.loc[df.duration < 90, 'movie_duration_category'] = 1
df.loc[(df.duration >= 90) & (df.duration <= 120), 'movie_duration_category'] = 2
```

Обратите внимание на две вещи:

- Сначала идёт присвоение значения всему столбцу, если присвоить только часть значений новому столбцу, тогда в столбце возникнут значения `NA` и столбец станет типа `float`, это не очень красиво, придётся его потом переделывать из `float` обратно в `int`.
- Круглые скобки в случае нескольких условий обязательны! Иначе возникает ошибка, которую вы упоминали: *The truth value of a Series is ambiguous*

Но я больше люблю вариант с использованием `Numba`, он позволяет записать условия в "человеческом" виде:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize
def duration2category(duration):
    if duration < 90:
        return 1
    elif 90 <= duration <= 120:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3 

df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': np.random.randint(1, 240, 100)})
df['movie_duration_category'] = duration2category(df.duration.values)
```

Ну, это всё как бы в дополнение к совершенно правильному ответу @MaxU. В `Pandas` довольно часто одни и те же вещи можно сделать несколькими вполне правильными способами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать так:

```
categories = {}
films = [{'name': 'random name', 'time': 154}]

for element in films:
    if element['time'] < 90:
        categories['one'] = element['name']
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте вместо `&` это `and`, ведь
`&` - побитовое И
`and` - логическое И

Comment: не сработало, я скинула новый код, который тоже не работает

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Этот вариант не сработает для Pandas.DataFrame

Comment: Да, без .loc и скобочек это не сработает само по себе